# Render a component multiple times depending on an event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

So I am working on a react project, and there is a card that needs to be filled in again and again depending on the use case. Sometimes the card will be filled only one time  and sometimes that same card has to be filled in multiple times, how can i get the card component to load multiple times depending on the use case. As soon as someone starts typing things in the first card, I want a new card component to be loaded at the same time just below the already available card component.

I have already created the Card component with input fields in the component, called it IndividualVendor and just one component gets loaded on the initial load. Further such card can be added to add more vendors.

here's the code for the main Beneficiary component and the card container called individualVendor.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BeneficiaryFilter from '../../Commons/Filter/Beneficiary/BeneficiaryFilter';
import AddBeneficiary from './AddBeneficiary/AddBeneficiary';

class Beneficiary extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div className="beneficiary-container">
            <BeneficiaryFilter />
            <div className="main-container">
               <AddBeneficiary />
            </div>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

 export default Beneficiary;


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import IndividualVendor from '../IndividualVendor/InvidualVendor';

class AddBeneficiary extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {

      };
   }


   render() {
      return (
         <div className="add-beneficiary-container">
            <IndividualVendor />
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default AddBeneficiary;
```

So basically the first component named Beneficiary, will have either one AddBeneficiary component or many of them loaded. I need to know what would be the best way to do this? Hope the question gives you some context. Any help would be very much appreciated, I am very new to programming and trying to learn as much as I can everyday. Please ignore if I have mentioned or asked something too primitive!!

Comment: Set the state depending on the parameters you want to use, and then use conditional rendering to display the child component(s)

Comment: I am not entirely sure, what do you mean by that, I can do the conditional rendering but what would be the ideal way to apply a condition for this, ideally I want the component to get added every time there is a click event in the previous card, suggesting that the user might need a new card.

Comment: I'll post a more complete answer in a couple minutes based on your requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I'm understanding, you would like the ability to add a card every time you have a click event in a previous card. You could then create a click function in the parent, pass it down via props to the cards, and let them call it when they're clicked. That could trigger another card to be added.

```
class Beneficiary extends Component {
   this.state = {
      children: 1
   }

   handleClick() {
      this.setState({children: this.state.children + 1});
   }

   render() {
      const { children } = this.state;
      let cards = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < children; i++) {
         cards.push(
            <AddBeneficiary key={i} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
         );
      }

      return (
         <div className="beneficiary-container">
            <BeneficiaryFilter />
            <div className="main-container">
               { cards }
            </div>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default Beneficiary;


class AddBeneficiary extends Component {
   render() {
      const { handleClick } = this.props;
      return (
         <div 
            className="add-beneficiary-container"
            onClick={handleClick}
         >
            <IndividualVendor />
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default AddBeneficiary;
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, Keno, I was able to implement that one and it seems to be working very well. Now I am facing an issue where I want to collect data from each <IndividualComponent/>  and add that as an object into an array that has to be sent to the server.
Any chance you may help me on this ?

Comment: @AshishNandanSingh sure, I can, but you might want to create a new question for that. If this question is solved you can mark it as such, and then comment the link for your new question and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Hey Keno, I have created a new question for this as suggested, you can find the link below, TIA for all the help, really appreciate it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54574307/collect-data-from-the-same-component-which-is-being-rendered-multiple-times-into