# Collect Data from the same component which is being rendered multiple times into an array to be sent to the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a create page where I am asking the user to fill the same form again and again for as many number of times the user wants, once the user thinks they are done with filling forms, they can click on submit button and all the data in the forms will be sent to the server.

I have tried creating a method on parent component and have the data collected from the same form component and send it back to parent. But there is no way for me segregate which form is sending the data. Incase the user has made some changes after adding data in the first form and then adds 3 more forms and fill them, then comes back and make changes to the first form before sending the multiple form data to the server.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import BeneficiaryFilter from 
'../../Commons/Filter/Beneficiary/BeneficiaryFilter'
import './style.scss'
import IndividualVendor from './IndividualVendor/InvidualVendor'
import Select from 'react-select'

// import actions to get data
import { fetchCompanyConfiguration } from 
'../../../../redux/vendor_payments/dashboard/actions/newPayTicket'

class Beneficiary extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      vendorTotalAmount: 0,
      vendorTotalCount: 1,
      dataToBeSent: []
    }
  }

  /**
   *
   * Check for click event on name change , increase number of 
   *   vendor by one, nut just once.
   */
  vendorAdd = () => {
    this.setState({
      vendorTotalCount: this.state.vendorTotalCount + 1
    })
  }

  /**
    * @param {amount}, change the state value for total for the 
individual ticket and then send the amount to component that shows 
the total amount.
   */
  onVendorAmountChange = amount => {
    this.setState({
      vendorTotalAmount: amount
    })
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchCompanyConfiguration())
  }

  addVendorDetails = data => {
    let dataToBeSent = {...this.state.dataToBeSent}
    dataToBeSent[`Vendor${Date.now()}`] = data
    this.setState({
      dataToBeSent
    })
  }

  render () {
    const { newPayTicket } = this.props
    const { vendorTotalCount, vendorTotalAmount } = this.state
    let listOfVendors = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= vendorTotalCount; i++) {
      listOfVendors.push(
        <IndividualVendor
          key={i}
          vendorAdd={this.vendorAdd}
          onVendorAmountChange={this.onVendorAmountChange}
          newPayTicket={newPayTicket}
          addVendorDetails={this.addVendorDetails}
          count={vendorTotalCount}
        />
      )
    }
    return (  
      <div className='beneficiary-container'>
        <BeneficiaryFilter
          vendorTotalCount={this.state.vendorTotalCount}
          vendorTotalAmount={this.state.vendorTotalAmount}
        />
        <div className='main-container'>
          <div className='add-beneficiary-container'>
            {listOfVendors}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    newPayTicket: state.newPayTicket.configurationData
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Beneficiary)
```

Above is the parent component where I want to have the data added from each  component. The individual component has

```
State for the form, 
class Vendor extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      venodrName: '',
      vendorId: '',
      vendorAuthType: true,
      vendorAccountId: '',
      vendorAccountName: '',
      selectedBankAccountIfsc: '',
      selectedBankAccountNumber: '',
      unauthorisedBankAccountName: '',
      unAuthselectedBankAccountNumber: '',
      unAuthselectedBankAccountIfsc: '',
      vendorNarration: '',
      vendorCategoryId: '',
      vendorCostCenterId: '',
      vendorDepartmentId: '',
      vendorAmount: '',
      vendorTds: '',
      vendorGstDropdown: '',
      vendorGst: '',
      vendorDetails: {},
      errors: {}
    }
  }
```

IndividualVendor component is nothing but a form which has fields that can be filled, every-time some one shifts from the current form to the next form, I want the all the data from the field to be added in the array of the parent component and once the user is done, they can click on submit and send all the data collected in the dataToBeSent[] in parent component.

I am not sure on how to go about getting the data out of multiple times rendered same component and have the data stored in an object in the parent component, also how can I ensure that I store the form data only once even if the same form is being changed again and again.

for ex: if I started adding info in the first instance of IndividualVendor component, and then go to the next instance of the same IndividualVendor Component, I want to make sure that the array in the parent component has only 2 objects and not a new object anytime a form is being edited/changed. Below I have added the mockup for the design of the page, each row item is nothing but the IndividualVendor component and the container is the parent component. Hope all this provides enough context.

TIA!!

[mockup design of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E0Yg.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it:

1. Lift the state up to the parent component, which means your form component don't have any state, and only receive data from the props and render it. The parent component is responsible for storing and updating the data.
2. Give each form data a unique id, so that it will be easy to find and update it.

Here is a simple example (https://codesandbox.io/s/5v389j6vp4):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class Vendor extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      vendorName,
      vendorNarration,
      vendorAmount,
      onChangeName,
      onChangeNarration,
      onChangeAmount
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>
        Name : <input value={vendorName} onChange={onChangeName} /> <br />
        Narration :{" "}
        <input value={vendorNarration} onChange={onChangeNarration} /> <br />
        Amount : <input value={vendorAmount} onChange={onChangeAmount} /> <br />
        <hr />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const DEFAULT_DATA = {
  vendorName: "",
  vendorNarration: "",
  vendorAmount: ""
};
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dataToBeSent: []
    };
  }

  addVendor() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      dataToBeSent: state.dataToBeSent.concat({
        id: Date.now(),
        ...DEFAULT_DATA
      })
    }));
  }

  handleOnChangeName(e, id) {
    const newData = this.state.dataToBeSent.map(data => {
      if (data.id !== id) {
        return data;
      }

      return {
        ...data,
        vendorName: e.target.value
      };
    });

    this.setState({ dataToBeSent: newData });
  }

  handleOnChangeNarration(e, id) {
    const newData = this.state.dataToBeSent.map(data => {
      if (data.id !== id) {
        return data;
      }

      return {
        ...data,
        vendorNarration: e.target.value
      };
    });

    this.setState({ dataToBeSent: newData });
  }

  handleOnChangeAmount(e, id) {
    const newData = this.state.dataToBeSent.map(data => {
      if (data.id !== id) {
        return data;
      }

      return {
        ...data,
        vendorAmount: e.target.value
      };
    });

    this.setState({ dataToBeSent: newData });
  }

  renderForms() {
    const { dataToBeSent } = this.state;

    return dataToBeSent.map(data => (
      <Vendor
        key={data.id}
        {...data}
        onChangeName={e => this.handleOnChangeName(e, data.id)}
        onChangeNarration={e => this.handleOnChangeNarration(e, data.id)}
        onChangeAmount={e => this.handleOnChangeAmount(e, data.id)}
      />
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.addVendor.bind(this)}>Add Vendor</button>
        {this.renderForms()}
        <hr />
        <h4>Result</h4>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state.dataToBeSent, null, 2)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

#### Edit

> how can i handle the other issue of getting the card added every time
>   someone starts typing in any of the fields ?

see https://codesandbox.io/s/vvm4lj3nqy

1. Add a boolean `dirty: false` to each form data
2. on every input change set  `dirty: true`
3. in `componentDidUpdate` check if there is at least one form with `dirty: false`, if not add it.

Like this

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.dataToBeSent !== this.state.dataToBeSent) {
      const clean = this.state.dataToBeSent.find(data => !data.dirty);

      if (!clean) {
        // Add clean form
        this.addVendor();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey Thanks, for the answer, I see that you are using a button to add the form every single time, what would be the best approach to start with one form preloaded and have then go on adding a new form anytime a user starts typing in any one of the forms, just to make sure that the user is not clicking a button to add a new vendor form.

Comment: I guess I figured out the solution to my first issue, i can start by showing the form by not starting with a blank state, but with key and blank value in it, but how can i handle the other issue of getting the card added every time someone starts typing in any of the fields

Comment: I think this should work, let me check it out and be back if I would have any questions. Thanks again with all the help.

Comment: On other note I was wondering If I really have to write a separate function for all the fields that would change, can I just keep a name attribute on all my fields and keep the state updated with [e.target.name] in the setState ? Any thoughts on that ?

Comment: I can see that the solution you provided is working, but honestly I am still not entirely sure of how the whole is working, mostly the componentDidUpdate life cycle hook, and what you really did there? 

PS: I am very new to react and programming, please don't mind, TIA

Comment: I think I got that part, basically we are looking for a dirty key in all the objects and if there is any we end up adding a new card in the overall array to be sent to the server.